# Is it a good practice to save the types of permissions in a database table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, design-patterns, permissions

I was recently involved in a project that I needed to make a permission/role system, but I couldn't reach a conclusion on the matter.

Should I save the roles in a table and use them as an FK in the user table or just save the numbers of the type of roles in the user table, and document what types are possible to have in the system?

Any documentation that can help me and you can send me I appreciate it.

obs: i'm using hibernate and jwt to do the solution.

Comment: I assume the roles you mention are not database roles, but application designed. In most cases a user would have more that just role, and each role has more that one user. This sets up a many-to-many relationship. The best design creates 3 tables Users, Roles, and User_Role. At minimum the User_Role table contains 2 FK. Additionally there could "intersection" data on the User_Roles table. For documentation research normalization.